# Unable to fix syntax error in mysql query

Tags: mysql

What is the syntax error in this query? I am unable to fix.

```
SELECT 
    wsd.sid,
    wsd.data as node_id
FROM 
    webform_submitted_data wsd
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            wsd.sid, 
            wsd.data as md_email
        FROM 
            webform_submitted_data wsd
        WHERE
            wsd.nid=48 AND wsd.cid=5
    ) tbl_md_email tmm ON tmm.sid = wsd.sid 
WHERE
    wsd.nid=48 AND wsd.cid=4
```

Comment: Show the error message.

Comment: We would like to ask the same question: what's the syntax error?

Comment: Most probably the error is caused by the fact that you are using the same alias `wsd` for main table and for the table in subquery

Comment: Show some sample data and desired result, its pretty unclear what you are really after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    wsd.sid,
    wsd.data AS node_id
FROM 
    webform_submitted_data AS wsd
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            sid, 
            data AS md_email
        FROM 
            webform_submitted_data
        WHERE
            nid=48 AND cid=5
    ) AS tmm ON tmm.sid = wsd.sid 
WHERE
wsd.nid=48 AND wsd.cid=4;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick help. Now I got where was the mistake :)

Comment: Would you please enlighten us what's the *tip* and what did you figure out so we can learn too?

Comment: I used the same alias "wsd" in main query and subquery that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error is because you are using the same alias in two select: "*webform_submitted_data wsd*"

Try to change the alias:
"**webform_submitted_data wsd1**" and
"**webform_submitted_data wsd2**" (for inner select)

SP.